# some characters like £ show up is question mark

Tags: encoding

Ok not sure why but on this page here (my test site) http://www.prxa.info/ some characters like a £ sign should up as a black diamond with question mark inside.

I know I must be doing something wrong with a character set but not sure what? Database is set to UTF8 and so is the page encoding?

Answer (score 1):

You then need to send you page as UTF-8 encoding. This can be done 2 ways. The most easiest way is included below.

For HTML it is possible to include this information inside the `<head>` element near the top of the document:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Or for html5 you can use a shorter syntax:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Specifying_the_document.27s_character_encoding

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML source (at least as Firefox delivers it), the character is being delivered as a replacement character U+FFFD. You'll need to ensure that you don't change encodings at any point from editor via database to website. Make sure whatever database client you are using to insert data into the database is also using UTF8.

Comment: Well the table it's coming from to the new table are both set as the same. What's the best way to find out where it's getting changed?