# £ pound sign not displayed correctly in html document

Tags: html, ajax, encoding, datatable

[image]

I am using http://www.datatables.net/ datatables and the data displayed in the table is retrieved dynamically.

Can anyone please help?

The pound sign displays fine when entered in the html document itself. And it also displays fine when viewed in the ajax data url.

**UPDATE**

I have just realised the content of the csv file was not actually in the utf-8 form. How can I ensure that the uploads are in utf-8 form.

Regards

Comment: Seems like a charset problem. Try setting your website file's character encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Data entry must be in UTF-8. Database encoding must be in UTF-8. Page encoding must be in UTF-8. UTF-8 end-to-end or die.

Comment: possible duplicate of [some characters like £ show up is question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627563/some-characters-like-show-up-is-question-mark)

Comment: I have utf-8 end to end. that is why it is so confusing.

Comment: also, str_replace("£", "&pound;", $data) is not working on the ajax data. The data was parsed from a utf-8 csv file where £ sign is stored as £.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `&pound;` instead of a usual £? Also may need to set your charset to UTF-8

Comment: I assume he doesn't want to change rows of data if he stores them in for example, MYSQL. The character encoding is clearly the problem here.

Comment: the data is being read from a utf-8 csv file and output into a utf-8 ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I have now filtered the csv file for the pound sign before it was uploaded and the appended it later on. I am using this hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reject non UTF-8 files you can do this:

```
if( !mb_check_encoding( $str, "UTF-8") ) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
    die("File must be in UTF-8 encoding");
}
```

`$str` is the file contents read into a PHP string